# How to handle forecast data (melt and "unmelt") generated by modeltime prediction - lost variables

Tags: r, time-series, tidyverse, data-manipulation, tidymodels

below I created some fake forecast data using the tidyverse modeltime packages. I have got monthly data from 2016 and want to produce a test fc for 2020. As you can see, the data I load comes in wide format. For usage in modeltime I transform it to long data. After the modeling phase, I want to create a dataframe for the 2020 prediction values. For this purpose I need to somehow "unmelt" the data. In this process I am unfortunately losing a lot of variables. From 240 variables that I want to forecast I get only 49 in the end result. Maybe I am blind, or I do not know how to configure the modeltime functions correctly. I would really much appreciate some help. Thanks in advance!

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(lubridate))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidymodels))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(modeltime))

## create some senseless data to produce forecasts on...
dates <- ymd("2016-01-01")+ months(0:59)
fake_values <- 
  c(661,678,1094,1987,3310,2105,1452,983,1107,805,675,684,436,514,668,206,19,23,365,456,1174,1760,735,366,
    510,580,939,1127,2397,1514,1370,832,765,661,497,328,566,631,983,1876,2784,2928,2543,1508,1175,8,1733,
    862,779,1112,1446,2407,3917,2681,2397,1246,1125,1223,1234,1239,
    661,678,1094,1987,3310,2105,1452,983,1107,805,675,684,436,514,668,206,19,23,365,456,1174,1760,735,366,
    510,580,939,1127,2397,1514,1370,832,765,661,497,328,566,631,983,1876,2784,2928,2543,1508,1175,8,1733,
    862,779,1112,1446,2407,3917,2681,2397,1246,1125,1223,1234,1239,
    661,678,1094,1987,3310,2105,1452,983,1107,805,675,684,436,514,668,206,19,23,365,456,1174,1760,735,366,
    510,580,939,1127,2397,1514,1370,832,765,661,497,328,566,631,983,1876,2784,2928,2543,1508,1175,8,1733,
    862,779,1112,1446,2407,3917,2681,2397,1246,1125,1223,1234,1239,
    661,678,1094,1987,3310,2105,1452,983,1107,805,675,684,436,514,668,206,19,23,365,456,1174,1760,735,366,
    510,580,939,1127,2397,1514,1370,832,765,661,497,328,566,631,983,1876,2784,2928,2543,1508,1175,8,1733,
    862,779,1112,1446,2407,3917,2681,2397,1246,1125,1223,1234,1239)

replicate <- rep(1,60) %*% t.default(fake_values)
replicate <- as.data.frame(replicate)

df <- bind_cols(replicate, dates) %>%
  rename(c(dates = ...241))

## melt it down
data <- reshape2::melt(df, id.var='dates')

## make some senseless forecast on senseless data...
split_obj <- initial_time_split(data, prop = 0.8)  

model_fit_prophet <- prophet_reg() %>%
  set_engine(engine = "prophet") %>%
  fit(value ~ dates, data = training(split_obj))

## model table
models_tbl_prophet <- modeltime_table(model_fit_prophet)

## calibration
calibration_tbl_prophet <- models_tbl_prophet %>%
  modeltime_calibrate(new_data = testing(split_obj))

## forecast
fc_prophet <- calibration_tbl_prophet %>%
  modeltime_forecast(
    new_data = testing(split_obj),
    actual_data = data,
    keep_data = TRUE
  ) 

## "unmelt" that bastard again
fc_prophet <- fc_prophet %>% filter(str_detect(.key,  "prediction"))
fc_prophet <- fc_prophet[,c(4,9,10)]
fc_prophet <- dplyr::filter(fc_prophet, .index >= "2020-01-01", .index <= "2020-12-01")
#fc_prophet <- fc_prophet %>% subset(fc_prophet,  as.character(.index) >"2020-01-01" & as.character(.index)< "2020-12-01" )

fc_wide_prophet <- fc_prophet %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = variable, values_from = value)
```

Comment: to be correct, there were only 48 variables left. I suppose it has sth. to do with the initial time split (80:20, 20% of 240(variables) = 48), but I am still not sure about the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my full solution. I also have provided background on what I'm doing here: https://github.com/business-science/modeltime/issues/133

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(lubridate))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidymodels))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(modeltime))
library(timetk)

## create some senseless data to produce forecasts on...
dates <- ymd("2016-01-01")+ months(0:59)
fake_values <- 
    c(661,678,1094,1987,3310,2105,1452,983,1107,805,675,684,436,514,668,206,19,23,365,456,1174,1760,735,366,
      510,580,939,1127,2397,1514,1370,832,765,661,497,328,566,631,983,1876,2784,2928,2543,1508,1175,8,1733,
      862,779,1112,1446,2407,3917,2681,2397,1246,1125,1223,1234,1239,
      661,678,1094,1987,3310,2105,1452,983,1107,805,675,684,436,514,668,206,19,23,365,456,1174,1760,735,366,
      510,580,939,1127,2397,1514,1370,832,765,661,497,328,566,631,983,1876,2784,2928,2543,1508,1175,8,1733,
      862,779,1112,1446,2407,3917,2681,2397,1246,1125,1223,1234,1239,
      661,678,1094,1987,3310,2105,1452,983,1107,805,675,684,436,514,668,206,19,23,365,456,1174,1760,735,366,
      510,580,939,1127,2397,1514,1370,832,765,661,497,328,566,631,983,1876,2784,2928,2543,1508,1175,8,1733,
      862,779,1112,1446,2407,3917,2681,2397,1246,1125,1223,1234,1239,
      661,678,1094,1987,3310,2105,1452,983,1107,805,675,684,436,514,668,206,19,23,365,456,1174,1760,735,366,
      510,580,939,1127,2397,1514,1370,832,765,661,497,328,566,631,983,1876,2784,2928,2543,1508,1175,8,1733,
      862,779,1112,1446,2407,3917,2681,2397,1246,1125,1223,1234,1239)

replicate <- rep(1,60) %*% t.default(fake_values)
replicate <- as.data.frame(replicate)

df <- bind_cols(replicate, dates) %>%
    rename(c(dates = ...241))

## melt it down
data <- reshape2::melt(df, id.var='dates')

data %>% as_tibble() -> data


data %>%
    filter(as.numeric(variable) %in% 1:9) %>%
    group_by(variable) %>%
    plot_time_series(dates, value, .facet_ncol = 3, .smooth = F)
    

## make some senseless forecast on senseless data...
split_obj <- initial_time_split(data, prop = 0.8)  

split_obj %>%
    tk_time_series_cv_plan() %>%
    plot_time_series_cv_plan(dates, value)


split_obj_2 <- time_series_split(data, assess = "1 year", cumulative = TRUE)

split_obj_2 %>%
    tk_time_series_cv_plan() %>%
    plot_time_series_cv_plan(dates, value)

model_fit_prophet <- prophet_reg() %>%
    set_engine(engine = "prophet") %>%
    fit(value ~ dates, data = training(split_obj))

## model table
models_tbl_prophet <- modeltime_table(model_fit_prophet)

## calibration
calibration_tbl_prophet <- models_tbl_prophet %>%
    modeltime_calibrate(new_data = testing(split_obj_2))

## forecast
fc_prophet <- calibration_tbl_prophet %>%
    modeltime_forecast(
        new_data = testing(split_obj_2),
        actual_data = data,
        keep_data = TRUE
    ) 

fc_prophet %>%
    filter(as.numeric(variable) %in% 1:9) %>%
    group_by(variable) %>%
    plot_modeltime_forecast(.facet_ncol = 3)

## "unmelt" that bastard again
# fc_prophet <- fc_prophet %>% filter(str_detect(.key,  "prediction"))
# fc_prophet <- fc_prophet[,c(4,9,10)]
# fc_prophet <- dplyr::filter(fc_prophet, .index >= "2020-01-01", .index <= "2020-12-01")
# #fc_prophet <- fc_prophet %>% subset(fc_prophet,  as.character(.index) >"2020-01-01" & as.character(.index)< "2020-12-01" )
# 
# fc_wide_prophet <- fc_prophet %>% 
#     pivot_wider(names_from = variable, values_from = value)


# Make a future forecast

refit_tbl_prophet <- calibration_tbl_prophet %>%
    modeltime_refit(data = data)

future_fc_prophet <- refit_tbl_prophet %>%
    modeltime_forecast(
        new_data = data %>% group_by(variable) %>% future_frame(.length_out = "1 year"),
        actual_data = data,
        keep_data = TRUE
    )

future_fc_prophet %>%
    filter(as.numeric(variable) %in% 1:9) %>%
    group_by(variable) %>%
    plot_modeltime_forecast(.facet_ncol = 3)

# Reformat as wide

future_wide_tbl <- future_fc_prophet %>%
    filter(.key == "prediction") %>%
    select(.model_id, .model_desc, dates, variable, .value) %>%
    pivot_wider(
        id_cols     = c(.model_id, .model_desc, dates),
        names_from  = variable, 
        values_from = .value
    )

future_wide_tbl[names(df)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response! I did just implement the solution, using the real data. Inspecting the results I perceived, that I am keeping all the columns know, what is great. Nevertheless I am getting the same forecast results (in and out of sample alike) for every variable. In my example above, you cannot spectate this behavior, as I was just replicating the same variable to forecast 240 times. I can send you an example code with randomized data to illustrate the above. Regards

Comment: Yes, you are getting a poor forecast because you are using prophet. Try xgboost with time series signature features. This is quite fast for forecasting with 1000s of time series using a single global model. I teach this in my course on modeltime. https://university.business-science.io/p/ds4b-203-r-high-performance-time-series-forecasting/

Comment: allright, I will experiment a little with different models like xgboost. Thanks again

Comment: Dear Matt, thanks for the advice to change from local to global models (which work just great). Nevertheless I tested on time series that start all at the same date. What if I have got like 200 time series with different observation start? If I predict them locally, there is no need to cluster them into time series chunks of the same length, as I can start every prediction from the exact time series starting date. My guess is, when I mix time series of different length into one global model, it won't give me satisfactory results and I need to do a lot of length clustering. Am I right there?